# In Tailwind's config, what is the difference between adding properties to theme VS theme.extend?

Tags: javascript, css, tailwind-css

Tailwind's documentation on its configuration makes multiple uses of the `extend` property, but doesn't clarify the difference of making customizations on the `theme` property VS the `theme.extend` property.

```javascript
module.exports = {
  content: ['./src/**/*.{html,js}'],
  theme: {
    colors: {
      'blue': '#1fb6ff',
      'purple': '#7e5bef',
      'pink': '#ff49db',
    },
    extend: {
      spacing: {
        '8xl': '96rem',
        '9xl': '128rem',
      },
    }
  },
}
```

What is the difference here? I've tested and it's possible to switch the colors and spacing properties around and they still work.

Answer (score 9):

It's pretty easy, `extend` extends default theme, while not using extend will completely override default theme for that property.

So in your example you will only have 3 `colors` in total, because all the default ones will be overridden.

But the `spacing` will be extended with additional values while preserving defaults too.